Starter circuit for small 12 V solar panel/submersible water pump
I have a small 12 V solar panel that powers a small 12 V submersible water pump.
The solar panel had a circuit that would start the pump running when the solar panel was putting out sufficient voltage. This circuit has died and I have removed it.
The pump will run happily on a low voltage from the solar panel (i.e. shady/half light), but will only start up on full direct sunlight.
It has an inbuilt capacitor that was before the (now removed) circuit, and if I let it charge up in say half light then plug the pump in it starts fine. So I guess what I am trying to say is that I need some kind of (simple) circuit that will only turn on after (the capacitor) has reached a certain voltage?
Thanks - Mark

Please add a block diagram

You need to place a P-mos between cap and pump and turn it on with schmitt trigger once the sufficient voltage appeares on capacitor.
The schmitt will make a hysteresis otherwise mosfet would be automatically turned off after pump starts to drain a cap (even a bit).


Don't forget that you need to supply the Schmitt trigger. But I think the + and - from the solar panel will do, provided you choose a Schmitt trigger with a wide enough supply voltage range

This will switch on motor M1 when supply voltage reaches a little over 12V, and switch it off again when the supply falls back to 6V or so:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Supply (photovoltaic cell) voltage is \$V_S\$ at node S (blue), and motor voltage is \$V_M\$ (orange):

The on/off switching thresholds are set set by zener diodes D1 and D2.
